# Reporting Multiple Response questions

Tags: powerbi

I have a csv dataset like this where we asked favorite colors:

```
id q1    q2    q3
1  red   blue  green
2  blue  green .
3  green .     .
4  blue  .     . 
5  .     .     .
```

Is PowerBI able to handle this type of reporting, I've seen recommendations to Unpivot the data which I could do BUT i would like to keep the results % based on respondents NOT on mentions, meaning % should be calculated by diving by 4 (people that answered a favorite color) son for example for RED result should be:

```
Green = 3/4 = 75% (based on 4 respondents)
```

Instead of

```
Green = 3/7 = 43% (based on 7 colors mentioned)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After unpivoting your sample data table looks like this:

| ID | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | q1 | red |
| 1 | q2 | blue |
| 1 | q3 | green |
| 2 | q1 | blue |
| 2 | q2 | green |
| 3 | q1 | green |
| 4 | q1 | blue |

Now you can use this **calculated table**

```
% Colors = 
VAR numIDs = 
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[ID])
RETURN
    SUMMARIZE(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Value],
        "Pct", DIVIDE(COUNT('Table'[Value]), numIDs)
    )
```

to get this result:

[image]